# Knife-solo prepare fails

Tags: chef-solo, knife-solo

I'm trying to configure a fresh CentOS 6.5 x64 node via knife-solo. But when I run `knife solo prepare root@centos` I get a strange error.

```
Bootstrapping Chef...
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 15934  100 15934    0     0  36862      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 95413
Downloading Chef 11.14.0.alpha.2 for el...
downloading https://www.opscode.com/chef/metadata?v=11.14.0.alpha.2&prerelease=false&nightlies=false&p=el&pv=6&m=x86_64
to file /tmp/install.sh.1750/metadata.txt
trying curl...
ERROR 404
Unable to retrieve a valid package!
Please file a bug report at http://tickets.opscode.com
Project: Chef
Component: Packages
Label: Omnibus
Version: 11.14.0.alpha.2

Please detail your operating system type, version and any other relevant details
Metadata URL: https://www.opscode.com/chef/metadata?v=11.14.0.alpha.2&prerelease=false&nightlies=false&p=el&pv=6&m=x86_64
```

When I try to debug that thing and run `knife solo prepare -VV root@centos` I get this: https://gist.github.com/Almaron/5709a69e09bad92f3475

I've tried to google it and found that it might be a proxy issue, but I have not set up any proxies what so ever.

**UPDATE**

Tried running `knife solo prepare root@centos--bootstrap-version 11.12.0`
Here's the result: https://gist.github.com/Almaron/2f7987f314132c80b8ed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the same problem. It seems there is a problem on the opscode site with version 11.14.0.alpha.2 - the http code returned is 404 Not Found. 
A solution is to pin the chef version when preparing knife solo:

```
knife solo prepare root@centos --bootstrap-version 11.12.0
```

Comment: That changed the output, but did not work quite well. I updated the question with the link to that result.

Comment: Em.. it somehow worked when I tried the same command again. Strange, but works for me. Thanks a lot.